# Android appindexing integration

Tags: java, android, android-app-indexing, google-search-platform

I'm trying to integrate the new app indexing into my application.  I'm following the official guide from google:

https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/appindexingapi

and it seems the google play services are still version 17 and does not have the appindexing class

```
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
```

The import com.google.android.gms.appindexing cannot be resolved. Is it my fault or google have not publish the new playservices library. Do you know where i can find it (com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.40)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

today google released Google play services version 18 in the SDK. this solved my problem